# Grafana does not show graphs for longer time periods

Tags: grafana

We are using Grafana to visualise some times measured with an other application. I get a data point every 5 min.
I also get a nice graph if I only visualise the last 24 or 48h.
for longer time ranges no graph is shown.

I researched a little and found that in the database there are data points each minute. which means I only get one value and 4 time NULL every 5 minutes. For a time range bigger 48h grafana starts to cumulate the values it ends up with only NULL values.
Here are two pictures which show my problem:

[Timerange 24h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJtLC.png)

[Timerange 7 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poudS.png)

Are there some settings I can make to avoid this behaviour?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using graphite? If so, please make sure you configured [xFilesFactor](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html) correctly.